# FIFA 15 2v2 with two Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, fifa-15

My friend and I have 2 Xbox One consoles and 4 controllers (2 each).

Let P1 + P2 be connected to Console1 and P3 + P4 be connected to Console2.

We **can** play 2v2 if P1 + P2 are on the same team against P3 and P4. But we want to play P1 + P3 on Team1 and P2 + P4 on the other team.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

I'm 99% certain this isn't possible... shame it would be good if it did.